# MVC ASP.NET iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis

I'm developing a web application in ASP.NET MVC 5. Recently I started having issues with IIS randomly crashing without throwing any verbose exceptions.
All I get is:

> 'iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access
>   violation'

displaying in Visual Studio output console.
**This issue only happens when I use the web app in Internet Explorer.**

This seems to be related to issue described here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1400342/iis-express-crashing-when-debugging-with-internet-explorer
My webapp also uses websockets via SignalR.

Specs:

- Internet Explorer 11
- Windows 10 Professional
- Visual Studio Professional 2015
- ISS Express the one with came with VS

I did plenty of reaserch on the topic, but was unable to resolve the issue. Whenever I look for answers I only get "unsolved" forum posts. 
**Question:** I have to debug with IE 11 because that is one of the requirements enforced by the customer. Is there a way around the problem?

Comment: what is happening in your code at the time of the error? does the error happen at the same place at the same time? can you post the entire error message? what have you tried?

Comment: It happens when navigating to another page, or refreshing current page. So its the front end calling the controller and the controller accessing the sql database.

Comment: it seems similar to this bug report https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1400342/iis-express-crashing-when-debugging-with-internet-explorer however the fix was allegedly put into an update. the ticket is still marked as being active though. Just goes to show that windows 10 is still a publicly-available beta product I guess.

Comment: Thank you very much. This narrows down what my problem is. I still need to figure out a solution though.